# Прокси для вкладок в расширении Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, плагин, proxy, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь написать плагин для Хрома. Нужно подключить прокси для определенных страниц. Перечитал [доку](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) хрома. В итоге получилось применить прокси для самого popup.html(окно плагина), но никак не для вкладок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? На данном этапе должна получиться очень сырая версия [этого](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-for-chrome/iilpibhiihokecnbdkaminemnmecjfed?hl=ru) плагина.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ProxyTest",
    "version": "0.1",

    "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "proxy"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
            "js": [
                "static/JS/jquery.min.js",
                "static/JS/content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["static/JS/index.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "test",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**content.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("test");
    var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
            proxyForHttp: {
                scheme: "socks5",
                host: "*.*.*.*",
                port: 65234
            },
            bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
        }
    };

    chrome.proxy.settings.set(
        {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
        function () {}
    );

    $.get('http://ip-api.com/json/', function (data, status) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    })

});
```

Когда этот код выполняется на вкладках(не в popup.html) в консоле видна ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (content.js:20)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ content.js:20
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась использованием pac-скрипта(есть в оф. документации) в index.js (background скрипт)

**static/JS/index.js**

```
  var config = {
    mode: "pac_script",
    pacScript: {
      data: "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {\n" +
            "  if (host == 'foobar.com')\n" +
            "    return 'PROXY blackhole:80';\n" +
            "  return 'DIRECT';\n" +
            "}"
    }
  };
  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
      {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
      function() {});
```